# Transition using this.router.push with tracking end of animation in VUE CLI

Tags: vue.js, transition, vue-router, lottie, anime.js

I really hope for your help! I'm a beginner, this is my first experience in creating web applications.

I work with Vue Cli, there is a lottie element that should be animated by click (I did it), then I should go to the “other page” (I did it) But, how do I implement the transition to the page only after the animation finishes? Help! You are welcome! For animation I use Anime.js

```js
<script>
import { translate } from '../js/animate'

export default {
  methods: {
    go () {
      translate(this.$refs.square)
      this.$router.push('Comprestore')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

```html
/vue

<template>
  <div id="animate" v-on:click = "go" ref="square">
    <app-lottie></app-lottie>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

```js
import anime from 'animejs'

export function translate (element) {
  anime({
    targets: element,
    translateX: 500
  })
}
```

Comment: You can listen for the event `transitionend` and then change route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [complete](https://animejs.com/documentation/#beginComplete) callback to wait until the animation is completed.

Now your code may looks like this:

```js
...
  go () {
    translate(this.$refs.square, () => {
      this.$router.push('Comprestore')
    })
  }
...
```

And

```js
export function translate (element, callback) {
  anime({
    targets: element,
    translateX: 500,
    complete: callback
  })
}
```

I create the example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-leaf-k2mdr).

In the example I also use page transition by using Vue built-in `transition` to transition between page. See [Enter/Leave & List Transitions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html) and [Transitions in Vue Router](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/transitions.html#per-route-transition).